# Cannot assign a value of type T to type T

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to create a reusable ViewController accepting a generic type. But I get this error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'LevelType' to type 'LevelType?'

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol SomeProtocol {
    var id: Int { get }
}

protocol VCProtocol: class {
    func showLevelScreen<LevelType>(level: LevelType)
}


class SomeVC<LevelType: SomeProtocol>: UIViewController, VCProtocol {

    typealias LevelType = LevelType

    var selectedLevel: LevelType? //Cannot assign value of type 'LevelType' to type 'LevelType?'

    func showLevelScreen<LevelType>(level: LevelType) {
        selectedLevel = level
    }


}
```

Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: What's the role of `typealias LevelType = LevelType`?

Comment: now it is LevelType = T as in my answer, I wasn't able to make this compile without the typealias, do you know how to do that?

Comment: I updated my answer without the typealias, thanks Cristik

Answer (score 1):

remove generic type in your function

```
func showLevelScreen(level: LevelType) {
        selectedLevel = level
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No complaints from the compiler when using this:

```
class SomeVC<T: SomeProtocol>: UIViewController, VCProtocol {

    var selectedLevel: T?

    func showLevelScreen<LevelType: SomeProtocol>(level: LevelType) {
        selectedLevel = level as? T
    }


}
```

Comment: Did your answer compile when you tested it? None of the two options you gave compiled when I tried them in XCode